How to split a plane into n-gon mesh as defined by the voronoi color texture?
The Voronoi color texture splits a plane into convex n-gons. How to get a mesh with the same topology with clean edges defining the color borders?


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune's_algorithm

You might look into cell fracture, as it does something similar. This pattern is created by distorting a grid, in this case 3-D, and slicing it with the 2-D mesh surface.

Incrementing on my idea from here:
How to achieve Geospatial Voronoi pattern?
For each non-top point of a cone I move it to the top of the cone and raycast down the cone (along the opposite vector to the one used to move it to the top of the cone) to hit another cone, and move there to find an intersection:

Clearly this is resolution based and imperfect, just a lazy approach:



.blend 4.2


I looked at the content you linked in the comments and racked my brains. I think the idea of putting this on the Z axis is brilliant! Even though it doesn't give the same result as the Voronoi Texture Node and still creates a lot of geometry in between, I love this approach (and of course the result)! Cool! A typical Markus von Broady answer!

@quellenform it absolutely does produce the same result as the Voronoi Texture node, you just need to synchronize the starting points: https://i.imgur.com/Rkz6qnL.png then the result lines up: https://i.imgur.com/Y1Ptppi.png

Ah, great, I obviously made a little mistake when testing. Wonderful!
